# Bitmask as member enum with default parameter

Tags: c++, enums, bitwise-operators, member, bitmask

I can't figure out how to implement a bitmask parameter for my class.
Specifically my **CreateMenuDlg** function

I've searched google quite a bit, finding all sorts of forum questions that ask about bitmasks, bitfields, etc. and everyone posts minimal example code
I keep finding people using **#define** but that wouldn't work for my class since I need to call it from main dialog with something like this:

```
DialogMenu *p_dlgMenu = new DialogMenu( this, &p_dlgMenu, this );
p_dlgMenu->CreateMenuDlg( ( DialogMenu::CLOSES | DialogMenu::WINDOW_HANDLER ), DialogMenu::DLG_CHECKOUT );
```

Here's my code:

```
class DialogMenu : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(DialogMenu)

public:
    enum dlgFlags
    {
        HIDES = 2^0,
        CLOSES = (2^0)+1,
        WINDOW_HANDLER = 2^1,
        MSG_HANDLER = (2^1)+1,
        DLG_SHOPPING_MENU = 2^2,
        DLG_DYNAMIC_MENU = (2^2)+1,
    };

    dlgFlags operator|=( dlgFlags first, flgFlags second)
    {
        return (dlgFlags)( (unsigned)first | (unsigned)second );
    }

    enum dlgType { DLG_CHECKOUT, DLG_INVENTORY_EDIT, DLG_SHIPPING_RECEIVING };

    DialogMenu( CDialog * const, DialogMenu ** const, CWnd* pParent = NULL );
    void PostNcDestroy();
    virtual ~DialogMenu();

    void CreateMenuDlg( dlgFlags paramFlags = ( CLOSES | MSG_HANDLER | DLG_DYNAMIC_MENU ), dlgType paramType = DLG_CHECKOUT );

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange * pDX);

    CDialog * m_parent;
    DialogMenu ** m_self;  
};
```

For which I'm receiving errors from my bitmask enumeration not being int.

```
dialogmenu.h(21): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'DialogMenu::dlgFlags'
Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

But my OR operator overload should be taking care of that cast!
If I have to I'll abandon bitflags altogether, but I'm trying to get the hang of them and I get more points on my project per C++ subject covered and bitfields was the most recent thing we learned. (Although we never learned how to implement them as enumerations, only playing with them on character variables.)

Comment: Doesn't applying the recommended cast from the error message fix your problem?

Comment: How do I do that? Cast it directly in the default parameter? I need users of this class (my group-mates) to be able to use the function with just DialogMenu::CLOSES and not have to cast it each time they call the function.

Comment: By the way, you know that ^ means xor, right?

Comment: Awh thats what was wrong with it. I didn't know that I just knew it wasn't coming out correctly so I had to go change it to Hides = 0, Closes = 1, Window_Handler = 0, Msg_Handler = 2, Dlg_Shop = 0, Dlg_Dynamic = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an OR operator for `enum dlgFlags`, instead it's an `operator|=` for `DialogMenu` (having 3 operands including `*this`, so it doesn't compile):

```
dlgFlags operator|=( dlgFlags first, flgFlags second)
{
    return (dlgFlags)( (unsigned)first | (unsigned)second );
}
```

Change it to

```
friend dlgFlags operator|(dlgFlags first, dlgFlags second)
{
    return (dlgFlags)( (unsigned)first | (unsigned)second );
}
```

`friend` keyword is needed to make it not a member of `DialogMenu`. Personally I'd prefer to move it out of the `DialogMenu` class together with `enum dlgFlags` itself:

```
enum dlgFlags
{
    HIDES = 2^0,
    // ...
};

dlgFlags operator|(dlgFlags first, dlgFlags second)
{
    return (dlgFlags)( (unsigned)first | (unsigned)second );
}

class DialogMenu : public CDialog
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: This one worked!<br>Just had to add DialogMenu:: scope for the casting after return.<br><br>Only reason I want it to stay inside class is because I'm trying to emulate fstream's ios::open, which is the instruction given by our instructor, so I need scope resolution to use class DialogMenu. <br>Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit cast for each value within the enum declaration itself.